# Which should I use? (performance)

Tags: css, performance

I want to know a simple thing:

when setting up a style that is inherited by all its children, is it recommended to be most specific?

> **Structure:** html > body > parent_content > wrapper > p

I want to apply a style to `p` but respecting these:

- I don't care having `parent_content` or `wrapper` having the style
- I do care changing the `html` or `body` style (or all `p`)

So what should I use?

```
#parent_content{
    color:#555;
}

#parent_content p{
    color:#555;
}

#wrapper{
    color:#555;
}

#wrapper p{
    color:#555;
}

/*...etc...*/
```

Also, some links to tutorials about this would be great

Comment: I think it depends upon the requirement.If your `parent_content` has many paragraphs and all of them having different property like colors,font-size and all then you have to give style to `parent_content p` otherwise giving style to `parent_content` can be good.

Comment: Apply te common style (here color) to `body` and you're done. It's also an accessibility requirement to put a color and background-color on `body` so no need to write the exact same thing for `p` here.

Answer (score 1):

In the matter of specificity, give an id to the `p` and use

```css
#paragraphid {}
```

But the answer depends what actually are your **need**. I will break down your code

```css
#parent_content{
    color:#555;
}
```

Will apply the color the text inside and may be inside its children also

```css
#parent_content p{
    color:#555;
}
```

Will apply the color to all the `p` inside #parent_content and its children

```css
#wrapper{
    color:#555;
}
```

Will apply the color to all the text inside it, and of its children

Comment: lets say I have tons of `p` and giving IDs is not possible. What is the best way to go?. And not that I don't like your explanations, but I already knew what exactly did every line, what I didn't know is the performance of every line.

Comment: @Yim, Definitely `#parent_content p { }`

Comment: but why, `#wrapper p` is more specific, are you saying specificness is bad? good? please I want explanation :D

Comment: `#wrapper p` does not only apply to `#parent_cotent p` but everything p, inside it. By narrowing down the selection to a specific container, if achieved what you want, without the creating any mess.

Comment: I don't care about the mess as long as it is faster, I think everything you are saying are just personal opinions. I want facts, I want to have the fastest that does what I want (without caring how messy or unreadable it gets)

Comment: @Yim, Ok, if dont care about the style being applied to other p elsewhere outside the #parent_content, then #wrapper p is faster